# Excel Average Formula Wrong

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

i am facing an issue with my Excel.
I have a statistic with two Filters (People >25 and People <25) which gave feedback (1-5).

I want to have the average out of those Feedback.

My Pivot is telling me People >25 AND <25 have an Average of 2,854

Single Output in Pivot: People >25: 3,169
Single Output in Pivot: People <25: 2,700

From my Point of view, it should be 2,935 and not 2,854. (3,169+2,700)/2

My Format in Excel is Standard, but i also have tried Numbers.

Any Ideas?

I am Using Office365

I tried to use the average Excel formular, and also calculate it manual.

Comment: In the end you mention you used AVERAGE() to calculate the average. Did it differ from the pivot average? What was the formula used; what range is used for your pivot data?

Comment: I used =average(P2:P170), but the point is, if i split it manual between <>25 i get different numbers when i /2 them at the end

Comment: just used, the Average function instead of sum

Comment: But that's the overall average, not the average of >25

Comment: But it should be the same if i have the average for < and > 25 and divide them by 2.. ?

Comment: Well, I. Think I don't understand what you're trying to do. You can't sum 2 averages and divide them by 2 to get an overall average.

Comment: Why not? That should be the same from my point of view ?! Or am I so wrong?

Comment: Nvm.. i am wrong, just google it... thank you!

Comment: is = 25 score included in the count?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is wrong:

Imagine having following values:

```
 5 <25
 6 <25
 7 <25
11 >25
19 >25
```

Average(<25) = (5+6+7)/3 = 3
Average(>25) = (11+19)/2 = 15
Total average = (5 + 6 + 7 + 11 + 19)/5 = 9.6

... while clearly: (3 + 15) / 2 <> 9.6.

I had almost forgotten this is an Excel question :-)
Hereby a screenshot:

[image]